# How to return a JSON object with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, nokogiri

I need to get a JSON object:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

In Rails, I'm using Nokogiri:

```
# Get the data
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(<URL>))
```

What I got back was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p><JSON-OBJECT></p></body></html>
```

I need to return just the JSON object so I thought this would work:

```
Hash.from_xml(data.to_xml)['html']['body']['p'].remove('\')
```

Nope. How do I get just the JSON object as if I used cURL in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd use Nokogiri to parse JSON objects. Nokogiri is for parsing XML/HTML. The default response type of Facebook's API is already JSON.

Better use [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday), or plain ol OpenURI and `JSON.parse`.

And here it is on cURL:

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET \"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Comment: Honestly, I thought nokogirl was to be used in these situation. I could not get faraday to work but httparty worked. Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of useful HTTP clients for Ruby. See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients for the list.

Comment: @theTinMan Ive hi just tried your answer and that also worked. Thanks but that seem advance for my knowledge at this stage 

Comment: It's based on a lot of hard-won experience dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally a JSON response is not encoded or included in a HTML page, it's returned as a text string which comprises the entire body:

```
require 'open-uri'

open('http://httpbin.org/headers').read
# => "{\n" +
#    "  \"headers\": {\n" +
#    "    \"Accept\": \"*/*\", \n" +
#    "    \"Accept-Encoding\": \"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\", \n" +
#    "    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \n" +
#    "    \"User-Agent\": \"Ruby\"\n" +
#    "  }\n" +
#    "}\n"
```

Parsing that back to a Ruby object is easy:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

JSON[open('http://httpbin.org/headers').read]
# => {"headers"=>
#      {"Accept"=>"*/*",
#       "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3",
#       "Host"=>"httpbin.org",
#       "User-Agent"=>"Ruby"}}
```

`JSON[...]` is a simple, generic, way to parse a JSON string, or to serialize a Ruby object. It's smart enough to know which way to do it:

```
require 'json'

foo = {'a' => 1}
foo.class # => Hash
bar = JSON[foo] # => "{\"a\":1}"
bar.class # => String
baz = JSON[bar] # => {"a"=>1}
baz.class # => Hash
```

If you want to be more explicit you can use the `to_json` and `parse` methods:

```
require 'json'

foo = {'a' => 1}
bar = foo.to_json # => "{\"a\":1}"
baz = JSON.parse(bar) # => {"a"=>1}
```

Note, at no time was Nokogiri necessary.

*If*, for some bizarre reason, JSON was injected into a page, or perhaps you wanted to get at some JavaScript data, which is a more likely thing, you could use Nokogiri:

```
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var foo = '{"a":1}';
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
script_contents = doc.at('script').text # => "\n      var foo = '{\"a\":1}';\n    "
foo = JSON[script_contents[/({.+})/, 1]] # => {"a"=>1}
foo.class # => Hash
```